# How to Post multipart/form-data in a POST request using Playwright IAPIRequest C#

Tags: c#, automated-tests, multipartform-data, playwright

Content-Type:
multipart/form-data

I am trying to send it using Playwright but getting Bad Request

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code worked for me

[image]